# Trying to download greater Los Angeles County - running out of memory

Tags: python, docker, network-analysis, osmnx

I am using a collection of python packages installed in a docker container; OSMnx to download OSM data and then networkx to perform the analysis - i proved my code on a small subset of data and now want to go to scale.

I am trying to do some commuter analysis in LA County - to do this, I need to grab streets extending somewhat beyond the county boundary because we let people commute from LA to other counties.  As a first cut, I wanted to grab California and then clip by a county-buffered polygon - after working away at it for a few hours, my container killed the Python process.  So, I thought i'd reduce the download to just a box using this code - even this fails in the graph_from_bbox method.  I have provisioned my docker container with 8 GB of memory.

```
greater_la_streets_box = ox.graph_from_bbox(35.114, 33.514, -117.439, -119.316, 
   network_type='drive', simplify=False,
   timeout=3600)
G_projected = ox.project_graph(greater_la_streets_box)
ox.save_graph_shapefile(G_projected, filename='greater_la_streets',
                    folder='/ds/data/spatial/network/streets/CA/')
```

Is it reasonable this would take 8 GB of memory to process?  If i read my docker stats right, the Net I/O is only ~36MB downloaded while memory usage quickly goes to 8 GB and eventually crashes the Python process.  There are ways to get around the process crash - i am wondering about the performance of this and whether there are more efficient ways to use OSMnx to download OSM data?

Comment: Have you tried using a smaller bounding box and slowly increasing it until it crashes? Also, not knowing OSMnx, are you able to grab multiple smaller boxes and merge the graphs?

Comment: I've just increased the memory to 10 GB to see if that is sufficient but otherwise your suggestion to see where the threshold is a good one.  I will try that next.  I can't seen to find a union method in OSMnx but certainly other python GIS packages offer this, so that's a solvable problem - the trick comes in how they will treat the boundaries.

Comment: Well, wouldn't you know it - increasing to 10 GB did the trick.  Though i may go back and see where certain thresholds are.   Still surprised that what appears to be 36 MB of data turned into a 8+ GB graph in memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it consume less memory by using a coarser graph representation.This can be done using the 'infrastucture' parameter.

```
greater_la_streets_box = ox.graph_from_bbox(35.114, 33.514, -117.439, -119.316, 
   network_type='drive', simplify=False,timeout=3600,
   infrastructure='way["highway"~"motorway|trunk|primary"]')
```

the below link provide more information on selecting more options for the way keyword in infrastucture
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway

Comment: Thank you - worth trying a few options.  I did manage to download a subset of the data (34, 33.7, -118.15, -118.5).  As @corsKa suggested, i could do this in tiles effectively and then union them.   I also don't like how the save_graph_shapefile organizes the results (a directory, then edge and node subdirectory, then distinct edge and node shapes)

Comment: Note the `infrastructure` parameter was deprecated and replaced by `custom_filter` in recent OSMnx releases. [See the docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.graph.graph_from_bbox).

Answer (score 1):

LA county is a moderately large study area, but I just tested on my laptop (8gb ram) and it downloaded/constructed the graph fine. Regardless, OSMnx downloads raw OpenStreetMap data and then constructs it into a NetworkX MultiDiGraph. NetworkX offers operators to combine graphs, for instance, via a union operation (see the compose function: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/operators.html).

You can do this operation in chunks and then merge the graphs together in the end. Or you can use a coarser graph representation as @Isfand suggests. Or you can provision more RAM locally.

> I also don't like how the save_graph_shapefile organizes the results

New feature requests are always welcome as issues on GitHub with proposals for redesigning OSMnx functionality.

Comment: Thank you Geoff.  I hadn't seen the Union operator.  Interesting that you were able to download LA County with 8GB - I wonder if there is something with how Docker is managing memory; guess i need to learn more about that.  I will make a suggested change to the save_graph_shapefile and if i can figure it out, maybe even code and submit as a pull request.